# Resetting value of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataFrame that has the following elements

```
146200  146218  146266       -1
146205  146203      -1   146234
146204  146207      -1   146300
```

I would like to reformat my dataFrame so that it becomes

```
0  18  66   -1
5   3  -1   34
4   7  -1  100
```

The corresponding starting values for `146200,146201,146300,...` is `0,1,100,...`, excluding the `-1`. Those are series as if I am not mistaken; I am not just sure how to handle them using pandas dataFrame. After reading my dataframe as follow

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
```

I am not sure how to transform it.

Comment: It is 100 actually;  I made a  mistake

Comment: Curiosity: what would happen if the first element is -1 (instead of 146200)?

Comment: it will remain -1; -1 is supposed to remain the same. I think we can use modulo 1462.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df = df.where(df == -1, df - 146200)
print (df)
   0   1   2    3
0  0  18  66   -1
1  5   3  -1   34
2  4   7  -1  100
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible implementation:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[146200,  146218,  146266,       -1],
                   [146205,  146203,      -1,   146234],
                   [146204,  146207,      -1,   146300]])

# leave -1 unchanged otherwise subtract a number "base" from the element 
def my_transf(x, base): return x-base if x != -1 else x

# Apply the transformation above to each element of the dataframe               
transformed = df.applymap(lambda x: my_transf(x, df.iloc[0,0]))
```